# Как изменять значение глобальной переменной

Tags: c++, строки

У меня есть переменная string str, изначально она пустая.
Так же есть рекурсивная функция F(n);

```
void F(int n)
{
    str += to_string(n + 1);
    if (n > 1) {
        str += to_string (2 * n);
        F(n - 1);
        F(n - 3);
    }
}






int main()
{
    string str = "";
    int z;
    cin >> z;
    F(z);

}
```

Мне нужно чтобы все значения операций записывались в строку str, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Сделайте указатель на эту строку и передавайте в рекурсивную функцию. Если без указателей, передавайте саму строку в функцию и возвращайте её.

Comment: Это не глобальная.

Comment: @bipll это вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

от лучшего к худшему

**способ 1:**

передайте вашу строку функции по ссылке

```
void F(int n, std::string& str)
```

**способ 2:**

передайте в функцию указатель на вашу строку

```
void F(int n, std::string* str)
```

правда внутри функции придется работать вот так:

```
*str += to_string(n + 1);
```

**способ 3:**

сделайте вашу строку глобальной:

```
std::string str = "";

void F(int n)
{
    // тут код
}

int main()
{
    // тут код
}
```

Comment: ко второму способу стоит добавить, что перед применением указателя нужно будет проверить его на nullptr

Comment: способы 2 и 3 можно было не приводить

Comment: @user7860670, в данной ситуацией да, но иногда нужен именно второй способ, я уже молчу про четвертый - использование синглтонов :)